# How can I recapture the specificity of old IPython filesystem path autocompletion?

Tags: ipython

On Windows, IPython is the easiest-to-use command-line environment I have available.  In my really old IPython environment (Python 2.7.5, IPython 0.13.2, and pyreadline 2.0), I used to be able to type a partial file path at the command line, press tab, and get something like this:

```
In [1]: cd /Users/Jez/D
/Users/Jez/Desktop/                      /Users/Jez/Downloads/                    /Users/Jez/dots2-default-accel=6da3a.pdf
/Users/Jez/Documents/                    /Users/Jez/Dropbox/
```

All of the options it presents are bona-fide files and directories. That's good.

With a newer setup (Python 3.6.4, IPython 6.1.0, (py)readline???) the following happens:

```
In [1]: cd /Users/Jez/D
                        delattr()          dir()     /Users/Jez/Desktop/   /Users/Jez/Dropbox/
                        DeprecationWarning display() /Users/Jez/Documents/
                        dict               divmod()  /Users/Jez/Downloads/
```

Despite the fact that what has been typed so far is *only* meaningfully interpretable as a filesystem path, the completion options include a whole lot of things that aren't files or directories (as if I might want to divide a non-existent object called `/Users/Jez` by something). This is less smart. I find it quite frequently derails my train of thought (in this example there are only 6 false positives, but sometimes there are so many that the bona-fide options are completely hidden).

Is there a configuration option somewhere that can allow me to re-capture the specificity of the old behaviour?  My search-foo has failed me so far - I've found a few references to readline and `.inputrc` but I suspect that's irrelevant for Windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it:

```
%config IPCompleter.use_jedi = False
```

or equivalently in `/Users/Jez/.ipython/profile_default/ipython_config.py`:

```
c = get_config()
...
c.IPCompleter.use_jedi =  False
```

Order 66 complete. What a relief.